# Why "Where to find “good” clients?" closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68724/where-to-find-good-clients

I specificity bold this line:

**I’m simply search for a site that ranks clients based on employer/freelancers opinions.**

I can't see how this question is a duplicates? The answers doesn't help either.

[Where to find clients?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46981/where-to-find-clients)

Comment: I agree that there's some difference between the two. On a side note, putting quotes around a single word or phrase usually creates [a negative connotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) (unless it's quoting something). I recommend not using them for emphasis alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is for a site recommendation, that's [off-topic here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Questions that ask "Where can I get X?"—recommendation questions—don't really demonstrate learning. I can ask "Where do I find good clients?" and likely get an answer, but then a few days later, I can ask "Where do I find good clients who have X?", then a few days later, "Where do I find good clients who have Y?"

None of these questions help me learn *how* to select good clients, and answers just become a glorified search engine. That's not what Stack Exchange is about. Instead, we want to help you answer *how* to select good clients so the next time the issue comes up (but with a slightly different set of circumstances), you can answer it yourself.

Additionally, it helps others who aren't in your same exact situation apply the question to their own situation, preventing multiple similar questions because the first question didn't exactly apply.

For more information, check out [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), which describes this problem in detail:

> If I had to summarize our network in a single word, that word is **“learning”**. People come to our sites to learn about topics they are passionate about. As the old Chinese proverb goes, “Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.” Every question and answer ultimately should be about teaching and learning — yes, even the shopping ones.